# is [data-empty] part of the browser environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I'm playing around with an open-sourced node.js project that uses socket.io. It has some code that checks whether the the length of `$('[data-empty]'` is greater than 0.  Although there was no class or id attached to it, I assumed from looking at this that data-empty was some sort of element in the markup, but it's not present in  the templates used by the application. Therefore I'm assuming it's some part of the browser environment but I can't find documentation on it.  Can you explain what is happening here with data-empty? What data is it checking?

```
if ($('[data-empty]').length > 0) {
        $('[data-empty]').first().attr('src', data.meat.chat.value.media).removeAttr('data-empty');
        return;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($('[data-empty]').length > 0)
```

Actually means 'If any elements with the data-empty attribute exist'

So, in the following document the code would run

```
<body>
    <div data-empty="true"></div>
    <div data-empty="false">foo</div>
    <div data-empty></div>
</body>
```

While in this, it wouldn't

```
<body>
   <div></div>
</body>
```

You can also select elements with a specific attibute value in a similar manner, like:

`$('[data-empty="true"]')` and `$('input[type="text"]')`

Answer (score 0):

It is referring to an attribute `data-empty`

So the query is looking for all elements with attribute `data-empty`

For example:

```
<div data-empty=42></div
```

Answer (score 0):

It checks if there are any HTML tags that have a `data-empty` attribute.
E.g. `<div data-empty="something"></div>` would match!